# ClassNotFoundException: ContextLoaderListener while migrating Spring to 4.2.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, weblogic, spring-2.5

I am migrating my project from Spring 2.5 to Spring 4.2.4. I am using weblogic to deploy my application. While publishing the project I get the below exception

```
    Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
```

The full stack trace

```
<Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1463992933692' for task '4'. Error is: 'weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101163]Could not load user defined listener: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.registerEventListeners(EventsManager.java:123)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.registerPreparePhaseListeners(EventsManager.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContextListeners(WebAppServletContext.java:1848)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.prepare(WebAppServletContext.java:1198)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.doPostContextInit(HttpServer.java:453)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.loadWebApp(HttpServer.java:428)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.registerWebApp(WebAppModule.java:976)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:384)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:517)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:159)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:648)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:191)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:44)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:208)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:98)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:217)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
'
weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101163]Could not load user defined listener: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.registerEventListeners(EventsManager.java:123)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.registerPreparePhaseListeners(EventsManager.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContextListeners(WebAppServletContext.java:1848)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.prepare(WebAppServletContext.java:1198)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.doPostContextInit(HttpServer.java:453)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.loadWebApp(HttpServer.java:428)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.registerWebApp(WebAppModule.java:976)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:384)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:517)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:159)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:648)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:191)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:44)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:208)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:98)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:217)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:395)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:517)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I have already checked that the libraries are on the classpath. Also there is no multiple Spring jars in my project. Is there any other reason why I may get this exception.
Find the spring jars on my build path 
[image: Spring jars in classpath]

In web.xml we have

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
```

One small hint is that once the project is being deployed I saw the deployed war in weblogic /web-inf/lib and found that Spring-web jar alone is shown as

```
spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar.jar
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you need somehow post more information...

Comment: @Jaiwo99 may I know what other information you require. We are not using maven.

Comment: can you please add more stack trace.